# Adding a Cordova Plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am currently building a cordova cross-platform app for Android and iOS.

After you add a cordova plugin say:

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

Are the libraries automatically added to the platform specific folder e.g. Android?
Or does the following command need to be run first to make it available in Android project?:

cordova build

Comment: the plugin will be added for all installed platforms. Installing a platform will also download the plugins for that platform.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is specified in your config.xml file. And then you can use it automatically, you shouldn't have to precise anything after that.